# How to get object by string in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have imported some images in vue file.
I also have a string related to these images, and would like to get them dynamically using the string value.

For example:

```js
import firstImage from '../images/first_image.png'
import secondImage from '../images/second_image.png'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      firstImage,
      secondImage
    }
  },
  computed: {
    myImage() {
      let str = 'first'; // this string value varies.
      return `${str}Image` // I want something like this to return firstImage (image, not string)
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to turn string into object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `firstImage` is in the data object you can just selecting it by `this` with name in `[` `]`

```js
import firstImage from '../images/first_image.png'
import secondImage from '../images/second_image.png'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      firstImage,
      secondImage
    }
  },
  computed: {
    myImage() {
      let str = 'first'; // this string value varies.
      return this[`${str}Image`] // I want something like this to return firstImage (image, not string)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you beat me to it! I also think op could simply name the properties of 'this' i.e. "firstImage": firstImage

Comment: @JTInfinite This is what `return {
      firstImage,
      secondImage
    }` does. It's short syntax for `firstImage: firstImage`.

Comment: yeah you're right of course

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of @S.Visser which is correct, but It seems that you want something dynamic (`str` should be dynamic) because the current logic returns always the `firstImage`, to solve this you've to define `str` as parameter for a  function return from the computed property :

```js
 computed: {
    myImage() {
     return (str)=>this[`${str}Image`] 
    }
  }
```

then you could use the property like `this.myImage('first')` or `myImage('first')` in template